# Don't "Conditional Format" blank cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I am applying a simple conditional format to column of values that formatted as currency. I am trying any cells that are "$0.00".

I have the conditional format for a "Highlight Cell, Equal To"and the value to equal is 0.

This cause any blank cells to become conditionally formatted as well. **Is there way to not condition blank cells when looking for a zero value?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a new rule for blank cells, and put them above the old rule (means it will take priority over your rule).

1. Create a new rule
2. Insert `=ISBLANK(A1)`. Modify `A1` to your top-left cell in range.
3. Don't put any format.
4. Click **Conditional Formatting > Manage Rules**
5. Select your new rule and click **^ arrow**.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule instead:

```
Format only cells that contain
Specific text
beginning with
0
```

This will produce the rule: `Cell Value Begins With '0'`

It will match `0`, `$0.00`, but it won't match blanks.